# Sufficient conditions for quotient ring to be Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, cohen-macaulay

We know that every Noetherian integral domain with (Krull) dimension $1$ is Cohen-Macaulay (**CM**). In a commutative algebra text the author have presented the following problem:
"Let $(R,m)$ be a **CM** local Noetherian ring with a prime ideal $P$ having dimension $1$. Prove that $(R/P,m/P)$ is **CM**."
I say $R/P$ is a Noetherian integral domain with dimension $1$, since $dim(P)=1$. Hence it is **CM**.
Am I right, or the condition that $(R,m)$ being **CM** is necessary to be given?
I appreciate in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: @user26857: I would also guess that $\dim(P)$ refers to $\dim R/P$.  karparvar: I agree that your argument is correct

Comment: Yes. In that very text the dimension of an ideal $I$ is defined as K-dim(R/I), or the sup of lengths of chains of prime ideals going up starting above $I$.